# Are questions about unicode on topic?

Tags: discussion

Is unicode on topic?

At the time of writing there are 380 questions about unicode here:

- see https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/search?q=unicode

I think that is a yes

However, is the design or content of unicode itself on topic?
(if not where should such questions be asked instead?).

---

For example take [this question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/161520/is-there-a-unicode-combiner-akin-to-a-superscript-style).

It was closed here but I got an [answer on regular stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76617653/1569204)
I don't personally see how that exact answer would have been off topic here but this is not my main community.

A similar not [question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/66878/unicode-superscript-numbers-1-to-3-vs-4-and-above) was was not closed.

Is a question about number of [cat symbols](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/51522/why-are-there-so-many-unicode-symbols-for-cats) really a more useful on topic question?

Comment: What do you mean by "design or content"? I suspect.. since question regarding font design/construction are definitely on topic, so would be unicode construction questions.

Comment: I didn't link to my orignal question at the time to avoid the meta effect. Now it is closed and moved elsewhere I am free to do so. It should demonstrate what I mean by "design and content".

Comment: Well as I read things.... your (closed) question is asking about construction of the unicode character set... not creating or defining unicode characters.. while the other two questions you've linked to, although nearly a *decade* old, do in fact ask about unicode features and not about altering the unicode specifications specifically. -- But this is just my opinion. the user base and mindsets change over time - it's hard to compare what was allowable in 2015/16 to what users find valuable today.